# Generating a model from an Oracle 18c database in EntityFramework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, oracle18c

I am using VS 2017, ODAC for VS 2017, and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100 (and its corresponding EF dll), and EF 6.4.

The database is 18c Express, and is running on a virtual machine.

When I had gone to generate the model, first I had troubles creating the connection string, something I fixed setting the `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)` in the sqlnet.ora, and then, on the next step, the wizard crashes. It just briefly displays a radio button "Entity Framework 6" and then exits.

The wizard creates no issues when I generate a model from the local Oracle11g Express Database, and also I haven't needed to change the sqlnet.ora for it to work.

Should I try with different versions of ManagedDataAccess, or is this something else?

Answer (score 0):

Updating ODAC to 18.3 made it work with both databases.